# Error on installing oursql for Python 3.1

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, oursql

I'm trying to work with oursql in python 3.2, and it's really not going so well.

Facts:

I downloaded oursql binary and ran the installer.
I have MySQL 5.1 installed.
I separately downloaded the libmysql dll and placed it in the System32 directory.
I downloaded cython for version 3.1 because there wasn't one for 2.7 or 3.2.

I have python versions 2.7, 3.1, and 3.2 installed.
I rebooted.

I now still get the `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.` error when running `import oursql` from the Python 3.1 shell.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I moved libmysql.dll to the same directory as python.exe, instead of in the DLL's folder, and it seems like it works.